# Importing CSV-files in R

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to load a csv-file into R, but fail. This is what I write:

```
airports <- read.csv(”~/Documents/TestRCSV.csv”, header=TRUE)
```

But I get the error:

```
Error: unexpected input in "airports <- read.csv(‚"
```

I use Mac, and I tried using the complete pathway with the same result. What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing path.expand... Use:

```
 airports <- read.csv(path.expand("~/Documents/TestRCSV.csv"), header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Let me know if you have further problems.

Comment: Please copy my code directly into your R session and paste the results directly from the R console